# How to append same table again with button and how to row data of table in another tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have developed a form where I am using some tables to get data where some key points related to these tables are:-

1. "AddNew2" button is for adding one more table like table 2 . Number of rows in Table 2 and all other tables added by using Addnew2 button will be increase if i click "AddNew1" Button of Table 1.
2. Table 1 is master table of getting same employee name is all tables. which means if I click "AddNew1" button then there will new row added in table 1 , table 2 and other tables and whatever employee name i am tyoing in table 1 will be copy in same in table 2 and other tables.

But I am facing some issues which  are:-

1. Whatever employee name i am typing in table 1, is coming perfectly in table 2 but it is not coming in table 3 , table 4 (which I added by clicking AddNew2 button.)
2. If I click AddNew1 button to add new row in table 1 , than one more row is increasing in Table 2 (say now table 1 and table 2 has 2-2 row). but now if I click in AddNew2 button to add same table like Table 2 than that Table is coming with only one table.

I am not able to solve this issue. I have added my code here as well please have a look.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insert66").click(function() {
    $(".copySubName tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName"> </td></tr>')
    $("#tableboth tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub"> </td> </tr>')
  });
  $('.copySubName').on('input', '.EmpName', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('table').find('input').index(this);
    //for second table
    $('#tableboth').find('.EmpName').eq(index).val($(this).val())
    //for 3rd table
  });
});


$("#insert17").click(function() {
  $(".individualSalSection").append(' <div class="portlet-body individual individualMarksSectionSub"><label class="label1 col-md-12 individual labelBoardName" style="display:none"> Enter Board Name </label><input type="text" class="form-control individual boardName"></input> <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual"> <thead> <th>Employee</th> <th> Marks</th> <th> is mandatory</th> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="subject1"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub"> </td> </tr> </tbody></table></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Table 1:-

<table id="table66" class="table table-bordered table-hover copySubName">
  <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insert66"></input>
  <thead>

    <th>Employee Name</th>


  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName">
      </td>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualSalSection">
  <input type="button" class="btn green individual" value="Add New+" id="insert17"></input>
  <div class="portlet-body individual individualSalSectionSub">
    <label class="label1 col-md-12 individual labelBoardName" style="display:none"> Enter Board Name </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control individual boardName"></input>
    Table2:
    <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual">

      <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th> Marks</th>
        <th> is mandatory</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if we are typing in employee name, it is appearing in subject, please correct that first

Comment: sorry for that mistake @AyushSharma . Can you help me in this question??

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not clear, so I am not sure what should be the correct solution, for you, please try below code and check whether you are looking for this. I have added each method to add employee name in new tables as well -

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smh1Ld7y/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insert66").click(function() {
    $(".copySubName tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName"> </td></tr>')
    $("#tableboth tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub"> </td> </tr>')
  });
  $('.copySubName').on('input', '.EmpName', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('table').find('input').index(this);
    var that = $(this);
  
    //for second table
    $('.tableboth').each(function(index,obj){
    
    $(obj).find('.EmpName').val(that.val())})
    //for 3rd table
  });
});


$("#insert17").click(function() {
  $(".individualSalSection").append(' <div class="portlet-body individual individualMarksSectionSub"><label class="label1 col-md-12 individual labelBoardName" style="display:none"> Enter Board Name </label> <table class="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual"> <thead> <th>Subject</th> <th> Marks</th> <th> is mandatory</th> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="subject1"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub"> </td> </tr> </tbody></table></div>')
});
```

```html
Table 1:-

<table id="table66" class="table table-bordered table-hover copySubName">
  <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insert66"></input>
  <thead>

    <th>Employee Name</th>


  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName">
      </td>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualSalSection">
  <input type="button" class="btn green individual" value="Add New+" id="insert17"></input>
  <div class="portlet-body individual individualSalSectionSub">
    <label class="label1 col-md-12 individual labelBoardName" style="display:none"> Enter Board Name </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control individual boardName"></input>
    Table2:
    <table class="tableboth arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual">

      <thead>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th> Marks</th>
        <th> is mandatory</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: row are not increasing if i click addnew button of table 1